# Keycloak proxy and APIMAN - token not found

Tags: oauth, proxy, access-token, keycloak, apiman

For my website, I wanted to implement APIMAN and keycloak as a solution so I came up with this architecture :

- Keycloak as an Authentification provider.
- Apiman as an API manager
- Nginx as a reverse proxy

Apiman is set behind a [Keycloak Security Proxy](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-installation-and-configuration/content/topics/proxy.html) that check whether the user is authenticated or not with this configuration :

```
{
  "target-url": "APIMAN_API_ENDPOINT_URL",
  "send-access-token": true,
  "bind-address": "0.0.0.0", // this is because I'm in a docker container
  "http-port": "8999",
  "applications": [{
    "base-path": "/",
    "adapter-config": {
      // HERE ARE MY ADAPTER CONFIGURATION
    },
    "constraints": [{
      "pattern": "/*",
      "roles-allowed": [
        "CUSTOM ROLE"
      ]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Everything was working fine until I tried implementing the Keycloak Oauth Plugin by following this [documentation](http://www.apiman.io/blog/gateway/security/oauth2/keycloak/authentication/authorization/1.2.x/2016/01/22/keycloak-oauth2-redux.html). Once configured, I kept having the same message returned :

> {"type":"Authentication","failureCode":11005,"responseCode":401,"message":"OAuth2
>   'Authorization' header or 'access_token' query parameter must be
>   provided.","headers":{"entries":[],"empty":true}}

I've been stuck here since two days now and don't know how to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error message tells you that your HTTP API request contains no `Authorization` HTTP header nor `access_token` HTTP query parameter.

You need to obtain JWT from Keycloak and then pass it via the header or query parameter.

---

Also you can check if you have only a single instance of *Keycloak OAuth Policy* in your policy chain.